# Override org-insert-link for those that match a pattern

Tags: org-link

I often need to keep track of conversations that happen in Slack, so I wrote a small elisp package that retrieves all message info (channel, timestamps, message(s)) for a given Slack permalink.

Then I convert the data to org-element using `org-element-interpret-data`.

Now, I need to find a way to either override `org-insert-link` so whenever I want to insert a link and it happens to match a pattern, it would not insert link as is, but extracts Slack data using my method and inserts that instead.

What's the best way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually [advising functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) can be used to change the behavior of a function. But for this interactive function it would get complicated when looking at the source.

Fortunately `org-mode` (version 9.1+) has a built-in method to add custom link types which is the preferred way in this case:

```lisp
(org-link-set-parameters TYPE &rest PARAMETERS)
```

An example that should come close to what you have in mind:

```lisp
(defun my-org-link-insert-slack-data (&optional arg)
  "Get the slack link and insert the data."
  (let ((slack-link (read-string "slack link: ")))
    ;; Use your function here to insert the slack data.
    (insert slack-link)))

(org-link-set-parameters "slack" :complete #'my-org-link-insert-slack-data)
```

Evaluate the example code and then run <kbd>M-x org-insert-link</kbd>. The custom link type `slack` can be selected:

[image: new org link type for slack]

Then it prompts you for the slack link and inserts the text entered at point.

Usually the completing function has to return a string. But as long as I have understood your question correctly you don't really want to insert a link. Therefore the  function just inserts the text itself. Org will show an user error in the minibuffer (`wrong type argument: stringp, nil`) but it still works.

It would probably be better to just use a function for this and not rely on `org-insert-link` at all.

Comment: Your edit to highlight that the completing read should return a string makes sense. But it can prompt for a description too? In which case would it then return the entire link? Or I guess org-insert-link should do that based on some flag. Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: If the function returns a string (just replace `(insert slack-link)` with `"text"` to test) you will be prompted to enter a description and then a link is inserted as follows: [[text][description]]. The prompt for the description is inside the `org-insert-link` function: `(read-string "Description: " initial-input)`. The function with `(insert slack-link)` will not prompt for a description as `org-insert-link` aborts beforehand because an error is signaled.